# csrf token on ajax with codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, codeigniter

I'm passing the token name and the token value to the view

```
$this->renderPage('client_ban',array(
            'csrf_name' => $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(),
            'csrf_hash' => $this->security->get_csrf_hash()
        ));
```

this is the html code(a twig template)

and this generates this code

```
<input type="hidden" name="csrf_test_name" value="18eb701019516cfa0af81679425333e1" id="csrf">
```

and this is the ajax code

```
var user_id = $('#user_id').val();
var csrf = $('#csrf').val();
$.ajax({
    url:'/ajax/client/ban_user',
    method:'post',
    data:{
         user_id: user_id,
         csrf_test_name: csrf
    }
}).done(function(response){

}).fail(function(){

});
```

and this is the HTML (a twig template)

```
<div id="client-info"> 
    <div class="cols-xs-12 col-sm-10">
        <p><b>Name:   </b> <span class="response-data" id="name"><span></p>
        <p><b>Surname:</b> <span class="response-data" id="surnames"><span></p>
        <p><b>Email:    </b> <span class="response-data" id="email"><span></p>
        <input type="hidden" id="user_id">
        <input type="hidden" name="{{csrf_name}}" value="{{csrf_hash}}" id="csrf"/>
    </div>
    <div class="cols-xs-12 col-sm-2 text-center">
        <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" id="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash" title="Borrado definitivo"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When The post request it's done is redirected to the same URL but making a get request, Do I missed something on the post request??

Comment: mention html code

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment

Comment: add your html form

Comment: I've added the html code, its not really a form

Comment: how are you testing that this is `GET` request and not `POST` ? AJAX code seems to be good.

Comment: Don't worry it's solved